# Get the Lissajous 135° Curve in C#

Tags: c#

I'm actually trying to get a Lissajous curve in a C# script for Unity 5.

[image: Curves]

It is the 4th starting from the Middle-Left, the 135° Curve. I already achieved the 45° Curve, but I can't get it's inverted variant in my C# script because of this "3π" I can't seem to reproduce with Mathf.PI.

I tried ((Mathf.PI * 3) / 4) and ((Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI) / 4), but it didn't worked. The curve is not the one I want.

Here's my piece of code from the 45° Curve I already achieved :

```
        float xU = 0, yU = 0;
    yU += yLissajousU * Mathf.Sin ((lissajousUSwaySpeed * 2) * Time.time);
    xU += xLissajousU * Mathf.Sin (lissajousUSwaySpeed * Time.time + Mathf.PI / 4);
```

I'm sure it's simple but I achieved the 45° Curve script just yesterday and it was the first time I was coding by myself.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution !

```
        float xA = 0, yA = 0;
    yA += yLissajousA * Mathf.Sin ((lissajousASwaySpeed / 2) * Time.time);
    xA += xLissajousA * Mathf.Sin (lissajousASwaySpeed * Time.time + ((Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI + Mathf.PI) / 4));
```

Just had to divide the yA SwaySpeed by 2 instead of multiply. The Mathf.PI addition seems correct.

Yet the x and y values are inverted. I'll try to fix them.